# Is there an option for multi-processor compilation with the Chapel compiler?

Tags: chapel

During compilation, I see that only one processor is used for compilation. I was wondering to speed up the compilation process if there is an option to add multi processor compilation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at present, unfortnuately.  That will likely need to wait until the day we have the time to rewrite the Chapel compiler in Chapel.